# Queryset of the foreign key Django

Tags: python, django

I have the model:

```
class Cliente(Endereco):
    email = models.EmailField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Compromisso(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    data = models.DateField()
```

How can I get the Queryset of de Client Model with Compromisso.date ?

Answer (score 2):

A queryset of Clients by filtering by compromisso.date (you put "data", i assume "date", as your question):

```
class Cliente(Endereco):
    email = models.EmailField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Compromisso(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    date = models.DateField()
```

queryset:

```
Cliente.objects.filter(compromisso_set__date=someDate)
```

Getting a Client and every date from associated "Compromisso"'s date is not possible without using .extra and doing your own sql. You can get them lazily as `aClient.compromisso_set.all().only('date')` for each Cliente (aClient) object.

Comment: I solved with this : Cliente.objects.filter(compromisso__data=data).distinct() . Thank you

Comment: mark one of the answers as accepted. it will hint the next people having the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.
You could get a `queryset` for all the `Cliente objects` and then iterate through them to get the `Compromisso.date`; something on this line:

```
queryset1=Clients.objects.all()
for cliente in queryset1:
     queryset=cliente.compromisso_set.all() # return all the compromisso objects
    # get all the date fields objects for all the query sets
     for c in queryset:
         date=c.data
```

Note: this is inefficient. unless you want to filter on a particular date, you try what Luis suggested

Comment: fix it. each client has MANY Compromissos, not just one. Each compromisso has ONE client (besides, the related name, as default, is compromisso_set)

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: yes, I fixed. how does this look?

Comment: Looks good. Inefficiency or not, it depends on the rest of the code. Sometimes the "inefficient" approach is the one needed.

Answer (score 0):

This helpe me:

```
clientes = Cliente.objects.filter(compromisso__data=data).distinct()
```

Thank you @Luis Masuelli